# Run CMD and ffmpeg Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use ffmpeg inside of my windows forms application and I'm apple to convert single file, but now I'm trying to select whole folder and run cmd ffmpeg.

I've tested with cmd and the below line converts automatically all files inside a whole folder, but I'm not aware how I can implement this of my winforms app. Anyone have a clue how to add this to my code?

`for %i in (*.flv) do ffmpeg -i "%i" "%~ni.mkv"`

Here is example code I use with convert a single file without PATH selection:

```
// Using OpenFileDialog to get Folder Path
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     openFileDialog1.ValidateNames = false;
     openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = false;
     openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
     openFileDialog1.FileName = "Folder Selection.";

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            textBox1.Text = folderPath;
        }
    }

    private void buttonConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string output = $"output--{DateTime.Now.Ticks}.mkv";
        LaunchCommandLineApp("sample.flv", output);
        Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select, \"" + output + "\"");
    }

    private void LaunchCommandLineApp(string input, string outputFile)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.Arguments = $"-i {input} {outputFile}";

        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the service you are expecting? Are you expecting somebody in this community to write some code for you for free? Please make sure that you take the [tour], and then read through the pages of [ask] to better understand how the site you've signed up to works. Generally we expect you to write your own code, and when it fails to do what it was written to do, without any problem, you'd post that code, and highlight the problem, in order that we can reproduce it, and then assist you in fixing it.

Comment: Seems to me that you already did the hard part, you just need now to use `Directory.GetFiles`. Your question could have been reworded as "_How can I get the files in a directory using c#?_". You already have an answer telling you how to use it.

Comment: try set `startInfo.WorkingDirectory` to your folder target, and `startInfo.FileName` set full path to `ffmpeg.exe`

Answer (score 0):

The DOS command you wrote is a for loop that repeatedly invokes the FFMpeg command. Do the same in C#, something like:

```
foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text, "*.flv")) //textBox1.Text == the folder path
  LaunchCommandLineApp(file, Path.ChangeExtension(file, "mkv"));
```

You might have to consider putting quotes in your command if your paths have spaces - your DOS command has them, your C# does not appear to have them.

Consider `$@"-i ""{input}"" ""{outputFile}"""`